# "System volume folder" always appearing in USB storage stick

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb, usb-flash-drive, windows-8.1

Whenever I move or copy video files from the PC (Windows 8.1) to my USB storage device and plug it into my TV, I always see a `system volume folder` on the USB device. This folder can be seen on the PC also, if I choose "view protected system files". My flash drive is formatted with a FAT32 file system.

> The question is, why is this happening on Windows 8.1, since I never had this problem on Windows 8 before upgrading, and how can I disable this feature?   
>   <sub>OK, that's two questions.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > System > System Protection (in the left pane) > System Protection Tab > Configure allows you to delete restore points, change the settings and change the disk space allocation for that drive

It is not a virus it is a system folder used by windows. However viruses can try to hide themeelves in that folder.
It is usually on each drive including your C:/ drive however it probably doesn't need to be on your Usb stick.

What is in this folder?
to get access to it right click it and click security then add yourself to the list so you have full control.

This should also help:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/how-do-i-prevent-system-volume-information-files/815b0046-d631-4419-a43e-44083a3733f5